# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes (RC4)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting some error in routing "Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Report/2000015'". I am using RC4 version
When I click on the left menu like "Group1" and then the sub menu like "CCA ECPOS" I get the above error message. 
I have replicated this issue in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ycXbUv2KenXOVPb8862g?p=preview

my route config is as below

```
path: 'Home',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            { path: 'ReportGroupList', component: ReportGroupList },
            { path: 'ReportList/:group', component: ReportList },
            { path: 'Report/:reportID', component: Report },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plunker showed some errors on the ReportList onSelect() method.

First, you pointed relativeTo to an object that didn't exist.  On this component the activated route is named `_ActivatedRoute` and you were calling it `route`.

The second thing is your relative path was wrong.  The defined path is `/Home/Report/:reportID`.  You navigate to `/Home/ReportGroupList` from which you then navigate to `/Home/ReportList/Group1`.  You then do a ralative path like `../Report/reportID` which translated to `/Home/ReportList/Report/reportID`.  You need a second 'relative up', so the link would be `../../Report`.

So the example onSelect could look like:

```
 onSelect(rptId)
{
    this._router.navigate(['../../Report', rptId], { relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, it works for navigating to ReportList, but when I again click on Group1/Group2 menu links it is broken and again I am getting the same error "cannot match any routes: 'ReportList/Group2'. please find the same in the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nsn6Pbox4CSJZWMEjqsx?p=preview

Comment: The issue is the same, your relative paths are wrong, this time because you are now navigating from a different path than you did originally (coming from just after login you will be at `/Home/ReportGroupList` - a two level path, but coming from a Report you will be at `/Home/Report/<reportId>/` a 3 level path.)  I think, since all your paths are absolute from `/Home` and not relative to current path you should stop using relative routerLinks.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/AY4YfFMUU8OuceG76KBF for updated code (and temp fix for an error leaving the report page).